# Oracle transaction table locking

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, transactional

Consider the case of updating 3 rows in 3 tables in a single transaction.

What's the performance consequences of trying to do this in parallel?

By **parallel**, I mean do several such transactions in parallel.

By **performance consequences**, I mean: Will some of the transactions wait until the first one finishes? Will only one transaction be performed and all the others locked until the locking one finishes? Is it row based? table based?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm#BABIGJBI) (Oracle 11.2):

> A row lock, also called a TX lock, is a lock on a single row of table.
>   A transaction acquires a row lock for each row modified by an INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, or SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement. The row
>   lock exists until the transaction commits or rolls back.

This means that for data updates, only the affected rows are being locked. If several updates are being performed on the same rows, the first one to "catch" the row will cause the others to wait for the row to be released (commit/rollback).

Also, this might cause a deadlock in the following cyclic update scenario:

```
Trans-A -> TA-RA -> TB-RB
Trans-B -> TB-RB -> TA-RA
```

Which means that updates need to always have the same table update sequence.

* Reads will not be locked and will see the latest committed value.

Comment: Why are you answering your own question? Was that a question for us or for you?

Comment: @sagi - Is there a problem answering my own question? It's still knowledge sharing. Others can use it.

Comment: SO exists to ask questions that **you** need an answer to them, not asking something you already know the answer for. It's not that you found the solution after you asked the question, you already knew it.

Comment: @sagi - [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: OK, I take it back.